# How do I call error message if user input wrong numeric data

Tags: java, swing

```
do {
    number = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Quantity : ","TRIAL",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if(number.matches("\\d+")) {
        qty = Integer.parseInt(number);
    }
    //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input !\n\nMin = 1\nMax = 100","TRIAL",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} while(qty < 1 || qty > 100);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,number);
```

if I put the error message inside or outside if, the error message still appear if user key-in right data

Answer (score 1):

You want to show the message if the input doesn't match the regular expression. So this:

```
if(number.matches("\\d+")){
    qty = Integer.parseInt(number);
}
//    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input !\n\nMin = 1\nMax = 100","TRIAL",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

needs to become this:

```
if(number.matches("\\d+")){
    qty = Integer.parseInt(number);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input !\n\nMin = 1\nMax = 100","TRIAL",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Now you're saying that if it matches OK then you read the new value of `qty`, but if it doesn't then you show the message.

You might think about an alternative, which is to avoid the regular expression, but just attempt the `parseInt()` call, and then catch the `NumberFormatException` that results if it can't be converted.

(You also need some logic to show an error if the number can be parsed, but gives a result outside the valid range of 1 to 100.)

Comment: The error message will appear if the user left it empty and put string only , but if user input the number outside the valid range it don't show the error message . @chiastic-security

Answer (score 1):

You can move a condition check into the loop and change your loop to infinite:

```
while (true) {
    number = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Quantity : ","TRIAL",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if(number.matches("[1-9]\\d*")){
        qty = Integer.parseInt(number);

        if (qty >= 1 && qty <= 100) {
             break;
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input !\n\nMin = 1\nMax = 100", "TRIAL", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,number);
```

In that case, you have an infinite loop, which will break only if the entered value contains only digits and it's value is within the range [1,100]

Comment: thanx u , its work . one more thing, how do I make number 01-09 invalid @Stanislav

Comment: @ZaemShakkir you can change the regex pattern to `[1-9]\d*`. it will accept only numbers with 1-9 at the begining

Comment: is it possible if I use the same code as you suggest to validate string , sory I'm still newbie in this java . hope u don't feel burden in helping me :) @Stanislav

Comment: @ZaemShakkir I didn't properly understand your question) you are free to use this code, sure, if it passes to your requirements

Comment: I mean if I want to validate textfield for string if user input numeric and left it empty by using the code given. is it possible ? @Stanislav

Comment: @ZaemShakkir yes, if the input is empty it will ask to repeat, because `[1-9]\\d*` mean, that must be atleast one digit

Answer (score 1):

> How do I call error message if user input wrong numeric data

I would instead suggest offering them a control which makes selecting a number, easy.  Specifically, a spinner with a spinner number model.  Like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PickANumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SpinnerNumberModel spinnerModel = 
                        new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 100, 1);
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(spinnerModel);
                while (spinnerModel.getNumber().intValue()<1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null, 
                            spinner, 
                            "Pick a number between 1 & 100!", 
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                }
                System.out.println(
                        "Number: " + spinnerModel.getNumber().intValue());
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx u for your suggestion but I couldn't understand the code because in my college I only learn basic java which is only using JOptionPane . The rest I only learned it from the internet . :) thank u once again @Andrew Thompson